# Convert array of custom object to AnyObject in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdata

In my app I am doing something like this:

```
struct Record {
    var exampleData : String
}

class ExampleClass : UIViewController {
    let records = [Record]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.records) as! NSData
    }

    ...

}
```

But in the last line of `viewDidLoad()` I got this error:

> Argument type '[Record]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep `struct` you can encode data using `withUnsafePointer()`: https://gist.github.com/nubbel/5b0a5cb2bf6a2e353061

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep `struct`, you can encode data using `withUnsafePointer()`. Here's an example, which I adapted from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/nubbel/5b0a5cb2bf6a2e353061):

```
import UIKit

enum EncodingStructError: ErrorType {
    case InvalidSize
}

func encode<T>(var value: T) -> NSData {
    return withUnsafePointer(&value) { p in
        NSData(bytes: p, length: sizeofValue(value))
    }
}

func decode<T>(data: NSData) throws -> T {
    guard data.length == sizeof(T) else {
        throw EncodingStructError.InvalidSize
    }

    let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(1)
    data.getBytes(pointer, length: data.length)

    return pointer.move()
}

enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure
}
```

I added some error handling and marked the method as `throws`. Here's one way you can use it, in a `do`…`catch` block:

```
var res: Result<String> = .Success("yeah")

var data = encode(res)

do {
    var decoded: Result<String> = try decode(data)

    switch decoded {
    case .Failure:
        "failure"
    case .Success(let v):
        "success: \(v)" // => "success: yeah"
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The error handling I added will not decode if the `NSData` length doesn't match the type size. This can commonly happen if you write the data to disk, the user updates to a newer version of the app with a different-sized version of the same type, and then the data is read in.

Also note that `sizeof()` and `sizeofValue()` may return different values on different devices, so this isn't a great solution for sending data between devices (`NSJSONSerialization` might be better for that).

Comment: Aaron and I spoke earlier today - changing `pointer.move()` to `pointer.memory` allows you to extend this code to reference types and objective-c types as well.

Comment: If I use GameCenter I must use NSData not Json, and transfer bytes between devices. What is the suitable method for that?

Answer (score 3):

`AnyObject` means any reference type object, primarily a class. A `struct` is a value type and cannot be passed to a function needing an `AnyObject`. `Any` can be used to accept value types as well as reference types. To fix your code above, change `struct Record` to `class Record`. But I have a feeling you may want to use a struct for other reasons. You can create a class wrapper around `Record` that you can convert to and from to use for functions that need an `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing:

```
    static func encode<T>(value: T) -> NSData {
        var val = value
        return withUnsafePointer(to: &val) { pointer in
            NSData(bytes: pointer, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: val))
        }
    }

    static func decode<T>(data: NSData) -> T {
        guard data.length == MemoryLayout<T>.size.self else {
            fatalError("[Credential] fatal unarchiving error.")
        }

        let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        data.getBytes(pointer, length: data.length)

        return pointer.move()
    }
```